# Is there any electric field inside a charged conducting shell, which is uniformly accelerated?

Tags: electromagnetism, acceleration

I know that the electric field inside a charged conducting shell is zero. However, what if we accelerate the shell uniformly? Does the charge distribution remain uniform? If not, is it possible for the new charge distribution to allow some electric field to penetrate the conducting shell?

I guess that the shell still resists the electric fields to be penetrated inside it even if the shell is accelerated, however, I cannot prove it.